# bt-hci btu_ble_process_adv_pkt still runs after iBeaconManager.unBind(this); is called onDestroy()

Tags: android, ibeacon

I am using Radius Networks iBeacon library for Android to build my first Android app. It's been really easy to implement the library and I've got a half-decent demo app working (thanks a lot davidgyoung!).

I am now trying to iron out the kinks. My app works as a demo whereby a user needs to tick off 3 checkboxes by going near 3 iBeacons. They are then presented with an activity that asks if they want to do it again with a button to restart.

The function that displays the 'completed' activity also finish()s the 'checkbox' (ranging) activity, and onDestroy calls the unBind method of iBeaconManager.

Intermittently, after a restart the iBeacons aren't picked up and LogCat is spits out this forevermore.

```
02-18 14:52:38.800: I/bt-hci(1392): BLE HCI(id=62) event = 0x02)
02-18 14:52:38.800: I/bt-hci(1392): btu_ble_process_adv_pkt
02-18 14:52:38.850: I/bt-hci(1392): BLE HCI(id=62) event = 0x02)
02-18 14:52:38.850: I/bt-hci(1392): btu_ble_process_adv_pkt
02-18 14:52:38.910: W/bt-btif(1392):  bta_dm_ble_observe BTM_BleObserve  failed. status 2
02-18 14:52:38.980: I/bt-hci(1392): BLE HCI(id=62) event = 0x02)
```

It usually happens on the second/third run of the app.
My hunch is that it is because of a failing with

```
iBeaconManager.unBind(this);
```

not releasing the BT stack properly, so ending up with two instances overlapping.

Could anyone shed some light on this because I've reached a point where I'm not getting anywhere.

Please let me know if you'd like to see more code.

Best

Andrew

Comment: I actually had these values set to the same thing and at 400 ms no less! iBeaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(ranging_frequency); iBeaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(100000); I would like to know if there is a way to completely stop the BackgroundScan though if anyone has any ideas? Cheers

Comment: This probably deserves a question of its own.  The IBeaconService should stop completely if you properly unbind() with the IBeaconManager.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue does have to do with binding to/unbinding from the service.  This should be no problem doing what you describe *if* the code always unbinds before rebinding later.  It is hard to say for sure what is going wrong without seeing the code (or a simplified version that reproduces the problem.)

I would suggest adding a log statement when you bind and another when you unbind, then run the app and make sure they match up.  The Android life cycle can be tricky.  I bet you will find that there is a mismatch.  Are you sure the on Destroy() is always getting called?

Understand that if `iBeaconManager.unbind()` is called when no other clients are bound, the IBeaconService will stop, and LogCat should confirm this.  If you later rebind, it will simply start back up again.  Are you seeing this?

One other tip: if you have two apps running on your phone using the Android iBeacon Library, you will have two copies of the service running.  This is by design, and should pose no problem, but might make LogCat output confusing.  Use settings to stop or uninstall all but one of these apps to aid in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well and tracked it down to a bug within the IBeaconLibrary itself. I was about to report the issue to RadiusNetworks but noticed on their GitHub that this was already found (or a similar bug with related cause) and was fixed in their current code. Unfortunately, it is not yet in an official release and so you'll need to download the source from GitHub and build the library yourself but I can confirm that after having done so, I am no longer seeing this issue.